# Error in android Code :Syntax error on token "Private", private expected also for "Public";

Tags: java, android, android-intent

```
I am Writing my first code to add and fetch some data from a database .:
```

Following is the code that I wrote in the Mainactivity.java file and its giving some errors 
Such as  Syntax error on token "Private", private expected also for "Public";
I have attached the screen shots as well can someone help regarding this .Because I am new to java and android codes

package com.example.ghrixdatabse;

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TableLayout;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static final EditText FindViewById = null;
    String fname,lname,email;   
    SQLiteDatabase db;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        db=openOrCreateDatabase("Mydb1", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Student(fname VARCHAR,lname VARCHAR,email VARCHAR);" );
    }
Private void Adddata(View view) 

{  
    EditText edittext1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.firstname);
    EditText edittext2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.lastname);
    EditText edittext3=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);
    fname= edittext1.getText().toString();
    lname= edittext2.getText().toString();
    email= edittext3.getText().toString();
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Student VALUES('"+fname+"','"+lname+"','"+email+"');");


}
Private void Showdata(View view)    
{
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(SELECT * FROM from",null);
    int count= c.getCount();
    c.moveToFirst();
    TableLayout tableLayout = new TableLayout(getApplicationContext () );
    tableLayout.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);

    tableRow = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
    textView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    textView.setText("Firstname");
    textView.setColor(Color.Red);
    textView.setTypeface(null,Typeface.Bold);
    textView.setPadding(20,20,20,20);
    tableRow.addView(textView);


    tableRow = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
    textView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    textView.setText("LastName");
    textView.setColor(Color.Red);
    textView.setTypeface(null,Typeface.Bold);
    textView.setPadding(20,20,20,20);
    tableRow.addView(textView);


    tableRow = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
    textView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    textView.setText("Email");
    textView.setColor(Color.Red);
    textView.setTypeface(null,Typeface.Bold);
    textView.setPadding(20,20,20,20);
    tableRow.addView(textView);

    tableLayout.addView(tableRow);
    for (Integer j=0;j < count;j++)
    {
        tableRow =new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
        textView1 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        textView1.setText(c.getString(c.getColoumIndex('fname')));
        textView2 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        textView2.setText(c.getString(c.getColoumIndex('lanme')));
        textView3 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        textView3.setText(c.getString(c.getColoumIndex('email')));
        textView1.setPadding(20,20,20,20);
        textView2.setPadding(20,20,20,20);
        textView3.setPadding(20,20,20,20);
        tableRow.addView(textView1);
        tableRow.addView(textView2);
        tableRow.addView(textView3);
        tablelayout.addView(tableRow);
        c.moveToNext(); 

    }
    setContentView(tableLayout);
    db.close();
}
Public void close (View view)
{
  System.exit(0);
}

}
```

[image: error for the private class over there]

[image: For Public as well]

[image: Third one is the graphical layout]

HERE is the XML FILE :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="49dp"
        android:text="FirstName" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="61dp"
        android:text="Lastname" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="E-mail" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/firstname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:ems="10" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/lastname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/lastname"
        android:ems="10" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/email"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:onClick="showdata"
        android:text="Show Table" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_marginBottom="26dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="17dp"
        android:onClick="close"
        android:text="Close" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
        android:onClick="Adddata"
        android:text="Create" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Use lowercase `p` for `private`

Comment: Syntax errors.. Use lowercase and there is no quote in rawquery..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `Private` to `private` and `Public` to `public`. `p` in private and public should be in small cases

Comment: (EditText)findViewById(R.id.firstname);
This is giving error as "Cannot cast from View to EditText"

Comment: @RanbirSingh check your xml file. Looks like something is wrong in that

Comment: I have attached the XML file as well

Comment: [I18N] Hardcoded string "FirstName", should use @string resource this is what it shows in xml

Comment: @RanbirSingh It works perfectly on my machine. Fix `private` access specifier error first then it should work

Comment: @RanbirSingh `should use @string resource` is just a warning, you can ignore that

Answer (score 1):

java is case sensitive, So use `private` instead of `Private` for access specifier. As `Private` is not a keyword and has no special meaning. Same applies for `Public`, use `public`.

Comment: (EditText)findViewById(R.id.firstname); This is giving error as "Cannot cast from View to EditText" what would have caused that

Comment: @RanbirSingh Error says it all, you cannot cast the view to edittext. I don't know much about android. I answered to your original problem. For following problems you can create separate questions.

Answer (score 1):

May this help you:

You are getting this Error because `java is case sensitive`, So, Change these lines:

- `Private void Adddata(View view)`
- `Private void Showdata(View view)`
- `Public void close (View view)`

**To:**

- `private void Adddata(View view)`
- `private void Showdata(View view)`
- `public void close (View view)`

**Edit:**

You are also getting error in this line also Check it:

- `Cursor c = db.rawQuery(SELECT * FROM from"// write here your table name,null);`

**Change it to:**

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM from"// write here your TableName,null);
```

Comment: (EditText)findViewById(R.id.firstname); This is giving error as "Cannot cast from View to EditText"  what would it be ?

Comment: I have attached the XML as well can you have a look please